# Return data from Objective-c to react-native

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I'm developing a module for react native, but I'm having some difficulty with objective-c, basically I have a method that should search for devices by bluetooth, and return the list of devices found, but I'm not getting it, could someone explain it to me ?

I have this code:

```
RCT_REMAP_METHOD(getDevices,
                 withResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 withRejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didUpdatePeripheralList) name:NIRScanSDKUpdatedVisiblePeripherals object:nil];
    [[NIRScanSDK manager] NIRScanSDKShouldActivelyScanForNano:@YES];

    NSString* result = @"NO_RESULTS";
    resolve(result);
}

-(void)didUpdatePeripheralList
{
    NIRScanSDK *nano = [NIRScanSDK manager];

    NSArray *visiblePeripherals = [nano.NIRScanSDKvisiblePeripherals mutableCopy];

    return visiblePeripherals;


}
```

Can someone explain to me how I can make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remap method's resolve / reject function can only call once.

You need make use of that to add / remove observer and make use of [RCTEventEmitter](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#sending-events-to-javascript) to send your devicse list.

Sudo code:

```
- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents
{
  return @[@"EventDevicesList"];
}

-(void)didUpdatePeripheralList
{
    NIRScanSDK *nano = [NIRScanSDK manager];
    NSArray *visiblePeripherals = [nano.NIRScanSDKvisiblePeripherals mutableCopy];
    // Not sure visiblePeripherals can be sent directly or not
    [self sendEventWithName:@"EventDevicesList" body:@{@"devices": visiblePeripherals}];
}
```